# C# How to properly reverse merge using SharpSVN

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

With my application, I am trying to revert the project back to a previous revision.  I have the revision number that I was able to obtain, I have the local target, and the URL of the repository. My code is as follows:

```
SvnMergeArgs mergeArgs = new SvnMergeArgs();
            mergeArgs.Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity;

        SvnRevisionRange svnRange = new SvnRevisionRange(stLogs[0].Revision, templateRevision);

        string MyRepo = http://myServ:8080/svn/Repo/Project/Development/trunk";

        SvnUriTarget MyTarget = new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(MyRepo));

        client.Merge(LocalProjLocation, MyTarget, svnRange, mergeArgs);
```

stLogs[0].Revision is the latest revision of the project, the current revision in the LocalProjLocation directory.  templateRevision is the revision that I want to reverse merge to.  MyRepo is obviously the repository where the project is located.  When I execute this code, I get an exception on the client.Merge() of "http://myServ:8080/svn/Repo/Project/Development/trunk isnt in the same repository as http://myServ:8080/svn/Repo"   Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem.  It seemed that the repo address was incorrect (case sensitive it seems).  It was http://myServ:8080/svn/Repo but I was pointing to http://myServ:8080/svn/repo.  Hope that helps anyone else...check the case of your URI.